# Botframework v4: Waterfall & LUIS.ai

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I tried to implement a simple booking chatbot to test LUIS.ai and Node.js Botframework SDK.
There is something which is not very clear for me: when a user sentence match with an intente which implement a `Waterfall` Dialog, each steps of this dialog will not go back to the NLU to extract entities ?

For example, I have a `BookingDialog`, implementing a `Waterfall`.
User say *"I would like to book a travel"*, the first question of my bot will be *"Ok, where do you want to go ?"*. At this step, my bot is waiting for a city. But, if the user reply *"lkjqbdfgoiqsjflqdis"*, the bot will go to the next step and say *"And how many people are you for this travel ?"*.

In this case, I would like to implement a solution where the bot reply *"Oh, I'm not sure to have understood ... Where do you want to go ?"* will the NLU does not match on a city.

Is it possible to implement this kind of dialog with Node.js Botframework SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement that with Node.js Botframework SDK. This is an [official waterfall sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt) that coded by nodejs. This demo mainly used for collecting information from users which similar to your requirement.

For your an other requirement that you need to verify the validation of users' city input , you should implement the judgement logic your self. As far as I know there is an API which provided by https://www.weather-forecast.com/ :

```
GET https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/ac_location_name?query=<the city user inputed>
```

If the city name is invalid , you will get a empty response , such as :

```
https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/ac_location_name?query=aaaa
```

And a valid one :

```
https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/ac_location_name?query=new%20york
```

Of course you can use [Azure map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address) to query the city too . Anyway , its all based on your own requirement.

For Q2 , you can add "Template utterances" based on your requirement into your Luis app so that you can exact the certain value i,e city name from sentences that users inputed . For details , [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern#template-utterances) explained it well.

Hope it helps .

Comment: How is going now  ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stanley for your reply :)

I understand your solution, this one is working if the user reply only with the city:

- Bot: *"Where do you want to go"*
- User: *"Paris"*

But, if the user reply *"I would like to go to Paris"*, the API will not understand the city. That's why I would like to go back to LUIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by by calling LUIS on any utterance in a waterfall dialog step:

```
/**
     * Second step in the waterfall.  This will use LUIS to attempt to extract the origin, destination and travel dates.
     * Then, it hands off to the bookingDialog child dialog to collect any remaining details.
     */
    async actStep(stepContext) {

        // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt)
        const luisResult = await this.luisRecognizer.executeLuisQuery(stepContext.context);
        switch (LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult)) {
        case 'BookFlight':
            // Extract the values for the composite entities from the LUIS result.
            const fromEntities = this.luisRecognizer.getFromEntities(luisResult);
            const toEntities = this.luisRecognizer.getToEntities(luisResult);

            // Show a warning for Origin and Destination if we can't resolve them.
            await this.showWarningForUnsupportedCities(stepContext.context, fromEntities, toEntities);

            // Initialize BookingDetails with any entities we may have found in the response.
            bookingDetails.destination = toEntities.airport;
            bookingDetails.origin = fromEntities.airport;
            bookingDetails.travelDate = this.luisRecognizer.getTravelDate(luisResult);
            console.log('LUIS extracted these booking details:', JSON.stringify(bookingDetails));

            // Run the BookingDialog passing in whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
            return await stepContext.beginDialog('bookingDialog', bookingDetails);

        case 'GetWeather':
            // We haven't implemented the GetWeatherDialog so we just display a TODO message.
            const getWeatherMessageText = 'TODO: get weather flow here';
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(getWeatherMessageText, getWeatherMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
            break;

        default:
            // Catch all for unhandled intents
            const didntUnderstandMessageText = `Sorry, I didn't get that. Please try asking in a different way (intent was ${ LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult) })`;
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(didntUnderstandMessageText, didntUnderstandMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
        }

        return await stepContext.next();
    }
```

This is the second step of the waterfall dialog in 'CoreBot', the LUIS sample on the [Bot Framework Samples Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs).

I see from your question that you're probably already looking at that sample. The problem with bookingDialog.js in CoreBot is that it's called specifically when your LUIS is not configured.